# How to use Collect in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, vector

For an input $n$, I have $n^2$ variables `uu[1,1],...uu[1,n],...,[n,1],...,uu[n,n]`.

I have an equation that is linear in these (e.g. `a1uu[1,1]+a2uu[2,2]+a3uu[2,2]+a4uu[1,2]` .

In this case, the equation can be written as `a1uu[1,1]+(a2+a3)uu[2,2]+a4uu[1,2]`. I want to collect terms according to these variables, and then determine what the coefficient of each `uu` term is, and store these in a matrix.

I've tried putting `Array[u,{n,n}]` as the second argument in collect, which works when the array is one-dimensional, but doesn't work in this case.

Has anyone got a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to write `Flatten[Array[uu, {n, n}]]` rather than without the Flatten. Problem solved now!